# Not getting validated_data.get() value properly

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am supposed to override the `create()` method on my serializer but I cannot understand why DRF cannot get me the real value of a `validate_data.get('some_field', None)`.

Here is my models.

```
class Heat(models.Model):

    # Fields
    performer = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    is_bred = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

class Breeding(models.Model):

    # Relationship Fields
    heat = models.OneToOneField(
        Heat, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Fields
    performer = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    remarks = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

And here is my serializer class

```
class BreedingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        heat_id = validated_data.get('heat', None)
        heat = Heat.objects.get(pk=heat_id)

        breeding = Breeding.objects.create(**validated_data)

        return breeding

    class Meta:
        model = Breeding
        fields = ['id', 'heat', 'performer', 'remarks']
```

Here is my validated_data looks like.

```
{
    "heat": 1,
    "performer": "Some person",
    "remarks": "testing"
}
```

When i try to print the `heat_id` it yield the value as `'Heat Object'` not the actual data provided as heat integer `1`. but it works well in this code `breeding = Breeding.objects.create(**validated_data)`.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I honestly doubt that the `dict` you printed is actually `validated_data`. It looks more like the raw data that was sent to the serializer.

Since `heat` is a relationship, DRF's `ModelSerializer` automatically instantiates the object with PK = 1. Also, *that* is why `Breeding.objects.create(**validated_data)` works. If you tried something like `Breeding.objects.create(heat=1)`, Django would probably complain because it doesn't expect the `heat` keyword to be a PK, but the object instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how can i get this to work sir? or what is the possible way to make get the heat actual value?

Comment: As `validated_data['heat']` already gives you the object you want, you could simply get rid of the first lines of your `create` method. If you want the object's PK for something else, simply do `validated_data['heat'].pk`.

Comment: you save my time sir! thanks for the answer! And i clearly understand now.